# iPhone + gridview

Tags: iphone, gridview

Is it possible to have something like Data Grid or Grid View control in iPhone?

Comment: In a native app? In a web app? Can you give some context to your question?

Comment: Sixten Otto, I am talking about adding the grid in my native app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to roll my own implementation, using a custom UITableViewCell with a configurable number of columns. I would just dequeue  this for each row, and set the data appropriately, according to the column I'm showing. I even put this UITableView inside a UIScrollView, with vertical scroll disabled, in order to have the table stretch more than the visible screen, and be able to scroll horizontally to reveal the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Arijasoft has got a static library

Arijasoft has got a static library using which developer can generate his own grid view implementation.

you can find the details [here](http://www.arijasoft.com/products/iphone-gridview)